# Change DIV content based on Toggle button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

If user click "Twin Bed" or "King Bed", Content inside "demand-message" have to change either "high demand" or "Only ??? rooms left".

ID will be same for button because of existing logic. Now my message to display on "demand-message" is not changing if i click "King Bed". It displays correctly for "Twin Bed".

Is it possible to change message by getting ID with data-bed-type attribute to match and change the message (either high demand or No. of rooms left)?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 left-container">
  <div class="demand-message--wrapper">
    <div class="demand-message"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-column">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" data-bed-container-id="deluxe-balcony-room" data-bed-max="190" data-bed-type="twin">Twin Bed</button>
        <button type="button" data-bed-container-id="deluxe-balcony-room" data-bed-max="90" data-bed-type="king">King Bed</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
function onToggleBed(e) {

    var thisButton = $(e.currentTarget);

    var bedTypeSelected = thisButton.data('bed-type');
    var bedValueSelected = thisButton.data('bed-value');

    var roomContianerId = thisButton.data('bed-container-id');

    var buttonMaxRoom = thisButton.data('bed-max');

    var message = '';
    if (buttonMaxRoom < 100) {
      message = 'Only ' + buttonMaxRoom + ' rooms left';
    } else if (buttonMaxRoom > 100) {
      message = 'In high demand';
    }

    if (message == '') {
      $('#' + roomContianerId + ' .demand-message').hide();
    } else {
      $('#' + roomContianerId + ' .demand-message').show();
      $('#' + roomContianerId + ' .demand-message').html(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that any hyphen characters will removed from the attribute name. Use camelCase instead.

Comment: Hi.. please check.. removed unwanted codes. I want to know how to change message based on button clicked

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, hypens will removed and turned into camelCase.

In this case use:

```
var bedTypeSelected = thisButton.data('bedType');
```

Let's `console.log(thisButton.data());` to see your data items.